# Implicit type conversion between uint8 and byte

Tags: go, type-conversion

As said in The Go Programming Language on page 55: "an EXPLICIT conversion is required to convert a value from one type to another", even if both of them have same underlying type.  For example:

```
type myByte byte

func main() {
    var a byte
    var b myByte

    a = b       // Compile error: cannot use b (type myByte) as type byte in assignment
    a = byte(b) // OK
}
```

But for `uint8` and `byte`, I'm surprised that the conversion is implicit:

```
func main() {
    var a byte
    var b uint8

    a = b // OK
    b = a // OK
}
```

So why?

Answer (score 9):

**byte** is an alias for **uint8** and is equivalent to uint8 in all ways.

From GoDoc:

> type Byte
>
> byte is an alias for uint8 and is equivalent to uint8 in all ways. It is used, by convention, to distinguish byte values from 8-bit unsigned integer values.
>
> type byte byte // Really: type byte = uint8 (see golang.org/issue/21601)

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#byte

Answer (score 3):

Earlier, on page 52 of [The Go Programming Language](https://www.gopl.io/), "the type byte is a synonym for uint8".

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
> uint8       the set of all unsigned  8-bit integers (0 to 255)
>
> byte        alias for uint8
> ```